# Querying ReferenceFields with MongoEngine

Tags: django, mongodb, reference

I'm playing around with MongoEngine and i just can't find the way querying ReferenceFields

```
Class Foo(Document)
    bar = ReferenceField(Bar)
    ...

Class Bar(Document)
    value =IntField()
    ...

bars = Bar.objects.filter(value__lt=1000)
```

Django:

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar__in=bars)
```

MongoEngine : ?

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9):

That is impossible by one query.

try this:

```
bars = Bar.objects.filter(value__lt = 1000)
foo = Foo.objects.filter(bar__in = bars)
```

More see. That test  scripts.
https://github.com/Ankhbayar/mongoengine/blob/dev/tests/django_tests.py#L73

Answer (score 0):

If you using reference you can't query on referenced object fields. Because referencing done internally in driver and most drivers save referenced document id, collection name and db name (so you can query only on referenced document id).

Want query? Use embedding or make two separate queries.

Comment: I  want to make 2 separate queries. Thats why i have the first query which grabs the referenced objects and than a second that filters documents containings these referenced objects

Comment: But i cant find a way to do the second query.

Comment: @PhilippeClémen: Can you post your documents structure here?

Comment: > (so you can query only on referenced document id).
But how would one do this?

Comment: Just look into document json, to see what what kind of json `ReferenceField` produce. And you will be clear of how to query by reference. I am not an expert in python.